# Cannot invoke and expression error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

Getting VSCode error while calling `request` function of `NodeJs Request package`

I am unable to find why VSCode is complaining about this issue?

So for the same I have created a separate function for calling `request() api`, but still, the VSCode error persists.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely its due to you importing 'request' module in a wrong way. The code below works as expected in node.js:

```
import * as request from 'request';

request(
{
    url: 'https://www.google.co.in',
    method: 'POST'
},
(res)=>
{


});
```

Comment: Make sure you have latest d.ts from tsd/typings. I have tried the code above it works fine in VSCode with latest definitions.

Comment: Yes, I have the latest type id file for

Comment: Can you verify that RequestAPI interface in request.d.ts file has the following declaration: (options: TUriUrlOptions & TOptions, callback?: RequestCallback): TRequest;